# Yes and no slider that hidesand shows a div?

Tags: html, css, forms

what would be the best way to make a yes/no slider that shows/hides a 2nd div like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/y3w896vn/

```
<div class="cognito">
<script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/s/p99R21F1QU65DzgfalAvcg"></script>
<script>Cognito.load("forms", { id: "2" });</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for an opinion? The best way is to use JavaScript to toggle a class on the parent element.

Comment: would it be possible using only css and any other code thats not dependent on script??

Comment: You can use the CSS `:target` selector.